# Arithmetic progression in difference sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ has positive upper density, that is 
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|A\cap\{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}>0.
$$
I would like to know whether the following statement for $A$ can be proven without applying Szemerédi's theorem on arithmetic progression:

For any integer $n$, there exists an integer $b$ such that $\{b, 2b,\dots, nb\}\subseteq A-A$, where $A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1, a_2\in A\}$.

Comment: Isn't $A-A$ empty?

Comment: $A - A = \{x \in A : x = y - z \text{ for some } y, z \in A\}$.

Comment: I would expect that it should be possible to modify appropriately the argument of Croot, Ruzsa, and Schoen (http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/kterm.pdf) who proved that if $A\subset[1,n]$ has size $|A|>(3n)^{1-1/(k-1)}$, then the sumset $A+A$ contains an arithmetic progression of length at least $k$.